# Only route specific IPs through VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, gui

I need to use a VPN from my work for pretty much only a few select URLs/IPs.

I configured the VPN with Ubuntus GUI, is it possible to just "whitelist" certain URLs or IPs and use no vpn for everything else in the in the .nmconnection file?